# SQL Join two sensor data on timestamp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've two tables which capture sensor data at different time and need help in writing sql query that joins these sensor data on time.

`sensor1` data (for simplification I made it every 5 mins but not necessarily):

```
sensor1_time      |  sensor1_value
09:55am           |  A
10:00am           |  B
10:05am           |  C
10:10am           |  D
10:15am           |  E
10:20am           |  F
```

`sensor2` data:

```
sensor2_time      |  Sensor2_value
9:50am            |  X
10:05am           |  Y
10:19am           |  Z
```

I want to join `sensor1` and `sensor2` table and output should be as follows:

```
sensor1_time      |  sensor2_time   |     Sensor1_value  |  Sensor2_value
09:55am           |  9:50am         |     A              |  X
10:00am           |  9:50 am        |     B              |  X
10:05am           |  10:03am        |     C              |  Y
10:10am           |  10:05am        |     D              |  Y
10:15am           |  10:05am        |     E              |  Y
10:20am           |  10:19am        |     F              |  Z
```

Comment: Please explain your logic to achieve the result.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  s1.sensor1_time, 
  s2.sensor2_time,
  s1.sensor1_value,
  s2.sensor2_value
FROM sensor1 s1
JOIN (
  SELECT sensor2_time, 
    LEAD(sensor2_time) OVER(ORDER BY sensor2_time) AS sensor2_time2,
    sensor2_value
  FROM sensor2
) s2
ON s1.sensor1_time >= sensor2_time AND IFNULL(s1.sensor1_time < sensor2_time2, TRUE)
```

Above assumes your sensor_time fields are of TIMESTAMP data type as it is stated in the Question Title

Note: `09:55am` is considered greater than `09:50pm` if to treat them as strings, which means you need to cast/parse them as time

So, if in reality those fields are strings formatted as in examples you provided - you need first to cast/parse them to proper data type - as in below simplified example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  s1.sensor1_time, 
  s2.sensor2_time,
  s1.sensor1_value,
  s2.sensor2_value
FROM sensor1 s1
JOIN (
  SELECT sensor2_time, 
    LEAD(sensor2_time) OVER(ORDER BY PARSE_TIME('%I:%M%p', sensor2_time)) AS sensor2_time2,
    sensor2_value
  FROM sensor2
) s2
ON PARSE_TIME('%I:%M%p', s1.sensor1_time) >= PARSE_TIME('%I:%M%p', sensor2_time) 
AND IFNULL(PARSE_TIME('%I:%M%p', s1.sensor1_time) < PARSE_TIME('%I:%M%p', sensor2_time2), TRUE)
```

If to apply later to sample data from your question

```
WITH `sensor1` AS (
  SELECT '09:55am' sensor1_time, 'A' sensor1_value UNION ALL
  SELECT '10:00am', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT '10:05am', 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT '10:10am', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT '10:15am', 'E' UNION ALL
  SELECT '10:20am', 'F' 
), `sensor2` AS (
  SELECT '09:50am' sensor2_time, 'X' sensor2_value UNION ALL
  SELECT '10:05am', 'Y' UNION ALL
  SELECT '10:19am', 'Z' 
)
```

result is

```
Row sensor1_time    sensor2_time    sensor1_value   sensor2_value    
1   09:55am         09:50am         A               X    
2   10:00am         09:50am         B               X    
3   10:05am         10:05am         C               Y    
4   10:10am         10:05am         D               Y    
5   10:15am         10:05am         E               Y    
6   10:20am         10:19am         F               Z
```

Comment: It is timestamp. I just kept string formatted to explain the problem. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could `JOIN` both tables and use a `NOT EXISTS` condition to select the relevant record in `sensor2`, as follows :

```
SELECT 
    s1.sensor1_time, 
    s2.sensor2_time,
    s1.sensor1_value,
    s2.sensor2_value
FROM sensor1 s1
INNER JOIN sensor2 s2
    ON  s1.sensor1_time >= s2.sensor2_time
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM sensor2 s20
        WHERE 
            s1.sensor1_time >= s20.sensor2_time
            AND s20.sensor2_time > s2.sensor2_time
    )
```

This **[DB fiddlde demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2a98d2a926d2668882f60105ee076ea)** with your sample data returns :

```
sensor1_time | sensor2_time | sensor1_value | sensor2_value
:----------- | :----------- | :------------ | :------------
09:55        | 09:50        | A             | X            
10:00        | 09:50        | B             | X            
10:05        | 10:05        | C             | Y            
10:10        | 10:05        | D             | Y            
10:15        | 10:05        | E             | Y            
10:20        | 10:19        | F             | Z
```